# c# class initialization code doesn't seem to work -- better way to do it?

Tags: c#, class, collections, initialization

I know I'm missing -or doing wrong- something basic, but after a day of search I can't figure it out. For prototyping purposes, we are using a 'global' public class with a list of persons (I know probably not a good practice for production code). We bind our DataGrids and other controls to this person list throughout our prototype. There is a Person class, an ObservableCollection with a list of Persons and a PagedCollectionView to do grouping / filtering (PagedCollectionView is what we bing to). I can't seem to do "default" grouping within the PagedCollectionView. I can't seem to add the grouping code within the class. When I add the grouping code to a screen it works, but that is problematic as the page recreated, it keeps nesting the grouping. Here is the code:

```
public class GlobalData
{
    public static PersonListClass PersonList = new PersonListClass();
    public static PagedCollectionView PersonListView = new PagedCollectionView(PersonList);

    public GlobalData()
    {
    // THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK. I CAN ADD THIS CODE TO A SCREEN AND IT WORKS FINE.
        if (PersonListView.CanGroup == true)
        {
                PersonListView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("RegionName"));
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
    // definition of person
    }

    public class PersonListClass : ObservableCollection<Person>
    {
        public PersonListClass()
        {
        // adding a list of persons here
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said I may have not structured right and / or missing something basic. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you debug it? What error exactly does it say?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I don't get an error message. It runs fine, it just doesn't group the items in the DataGrid. If I move the code section just below "//THIS IS THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK..." to a screen it starts grouping the items in the DataGrid. I'm using Expression Blend, so debugging options are somewhat limited.

Comment: are you calling GlobalData()?

Comment: Note that you are creating a new class of PersonListClass but the function GlobalData() does not belong to it

Comment: Again thanks - here is more info. On the screens where I have the DataGrids, I use 
MyGrid.DataContext = GlobalData.PersonListView
and this works, MyGrid displays the PersonListView (PagedCollectionView). It just does so with no nesting. Regarding your comment, GlobalData() -- no I'm not calling it. I'm not sure what you mean by "Note that you are creating a new class..." - how should that be done?

Comment: When you create the class, you add the persons, because you have it inside the class, but your GlobalData function is not, so it wont do it unless you put the function inside the calss.So you are not calling it, if you want to order them you should do GlobalData.GlobalData() right?